# What are the zero point energy densities of the individual quantum fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, cosmological-constant

I'm reading through "General Relativity - An Introduction for Physicists", by Hobson, Efstathiou, and Lasenby, and I have a question regarding one of the statements related to the cosmological constant.  They make the statement on Page 187, shown in the image here.

[image]

The derived expression (Equation 8.22) shows the cosmological constant as a function of several other known constants, as well as a “vacuum energy density” term.

They state that the simplest calculation of this term “involves summing the quantum mechanical zero-point energies of all the fields known in Nature”.  However, they do not show how this is done or what those sums are.

Can anyone provide the values for each of these zero point energy densities (ZPED)?  Basically I’m imagining a simple equation like the one below, but what are the actual values to plug in?

Total ZPED = E&MZPED + HiggsZPED + …

Any reputable references for these values would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22468/what-are-the-calculations-for-vacuum-energy