# Does following relation holds for an interacting vacuum of QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, vacuum

For a non-interacting vacuum of QFT we have $$\hat{P}^\mu|0\rangle=0$$
where $\hat{P}^\mu$ is the $4$- vector momentum operator having eigenvalue and eigenvector given by $$\hat{P}^\mu|p\rangle=p^\mu|p\rangle$$
Does this relation also hold for an interacting QFT vacuum $|\Omega\rangle$ i.e. $$\hat{P}^\mu|\Omega\rangle=0$$

Comment: See the answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239640/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the vacuum in QFT have nonzero energy or not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239640/)

Comment: Short answer is yes, this is one of the Wightman axioms – Poincare-invariance of the vacuum.